# Direct read MEMBER properties from C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, properties, qml

Is there any downsides, if I read data member (defined in `public :` section) corresponding to some `Q_PROPERTY` from C++ code, if `Q_PROPERTY` is non-`CONSTANT` `MEMBER` without `READ`?

```
class Value
    : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(int x MEMBER x NOTIFY xChanged)

public :

    Value(QObject * const parent)
        : QObject{parent}
    { ; }

    int x = 0;

Q_SIGNALS :

    void xChanged(int x);

};

//...
Value v;
//...
std::cout << v.x;
```

Surely it is attractive to use `v.setPropery("x", 123);` to write, because `Q_EMIT xChanged(123);` is called automatically in the case. But it is annoying to write `v.property("x")` instead of `v.x` every time when I just want to read the value of the property from C++ code. BTW it is not optimal in sense of runtime, I sure.

Is there any bad interference between C++ and Javascript/QML code in the case of direct read of data member of a class like above one?

Comment: It is bad to make fields public only because of OOP paradigm (incapsulation). So if you don't care about safe and readable code, you may use your fields as public members.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov from QML point of view I get access to data members directly. They are public. C++ side is the mirrored to QML side in sense of OOP.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov The only downside to make filed public is that I can't make it `const` for all but `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any bad interference between C++ and Javascript/QML code in the case of direct read of data member of a class like above one?

No. There isn't. But you should have an accessor, and not expose the member directly:

```
class Value : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int x MEMBER m_x NOTIFY xChanged)
    int m_x = {};
public :
    Value(QObject * parent = {}) : QObject{parent} {}
    int x() const { return m_x; }
    Q_SIGNAL void xChanged(int);
};
```

Comment: Now it is better to specify it as `READ` function. Because currently it is misleading to have getter and not use it in `Q_PROPERTY`.

Comment: In this case `x` became readonly property from QML side, though

Comment: The accessor is there for C++. It's still OK to expose it to the metaobject system via the member. Yet one could argue that changes to the accessor could be by omission not synced with `Q_PROPERTY` and then you'd have a problem. One could tweak `moc` to emit a helper class with accessors for `MEMBER`-only properties, and inherit from that class, e.g.: `class Value : public QObject, public ValueAccessors { friend ValueAccessors; ... };`. Easy enough to do and it'd solve the problem of `moc` being unable to add declarations to the class.

Answer (score -1):

It's perfectly fine to use MEMBER in a Q_PROPERTY knowing that doing so you lose the place to execute code WHEN the property is read or written.

Remember that you can use a mixed approach, using MEMBER but specifing also a READ or a WRITE, like written in the documentation.

```
Q_PROPERTY(type name MEMBER memberName [(READ getFunction | WRITE setFunction)])
```

You can use MEMBER at first and if you need a hook on read/write, you can add a getter/setter later.

Using the keyword MEMBER it's helpful to avoid useless boilerplate, with empty getters and setters that look all the same.

Comment: You write trivia. The question is not about it. You almost repeat what I write in question.

Comment: The question is it about the use of MEMBER if there are any issued about not having setters and getters in the interaction with C++ and QML, and the answer is that "it's perfectly fine", and I'm detailing pro and cons about using MEMBER.
Should have I just said: "No problems."?

Comment: Algorithm is the next: first of all do read the question and all the answers existent at the moment. For this question there is also discussion, which reveals some details. If you think, differently then other participants you may give an answer or post a comment with *really new* information. Your answer is only consist of background information already provided in the question itself. There is no problem with reading about Qt Property System. I am familiar with that and I've demonstrated this in the very first couple of lines in the question.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry if I misunderstood the point. I'll try to be more careful.